# Sending uint8clampedarray Array via ajax to c# in javaScript after getImageData from Canvas

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, ajax, canvas

I am creating a signature on the client side in `javaScript` and then trying to send the result to the code behind(`c#`) via ajax. The resulting array I am trying to pass is of type `uint8clampedarray` and I am unable to do, with the code behind method never being hit.
It is hitting the Page Load method but not the SetSignature method.

**javaScript**

```
var signatureByteArray = signature.getSignatureImage();
    SendArrayViaAjax(signatureByteArray);

function getSignatureImage() {
    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
}

function SendArrayViaAjax(signatureArray) {
    var sigArray = JSON.stringify( signatureArray);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { array: sigArray },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Intranet/OHS/SOP/SOPSignOffs.aspx/SetSignature",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d + "success");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("an error has taken place");
            }
    });
}
```

**code behind**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SetSignature(string[] array)
{
    var x = array[2];
    return "success";
}
```

My question is how do I send the array as it is as `uint8clampedarray` via ajax and how do I retrieve it in c#? Or is there a better way?

```
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");`
```

is how I am getting the the `Canvas` element.
The generation of thew signature works really well, it is just sending it back to `C#` which is the problem.

Comment: What error are you getting if you look at the developer console -> Network tab?

Comment: @Santi I have changed my question. No error, just thew method not being hit but the Page Load method being hit

Comment: @Santi  I have a solution posted below that works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to generate the canvas image data differently (old way).

**Generate Image Differently**

```
function getSignatureImage() {
    //return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
    var pic = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    pic = pic.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")
    return pic;
}
```

And then in then **ajax function**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: '{"imageData" : "'+ signatureImage + '" }',
    ....
```

And then in the **code behind**

```
public static string SetSignature(string imageData)
{
    string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Signature.png");
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```